# SQL Server: Show Plan for Locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, locking

I'm new to SQL SErver and wonderingif there anyway to :

```
set showplan_all on;
```

... and then run a multi-table query and have it show me the locks that are going to be held on each database object?

I'm particularly interested in finding the lock order so that I might be able to decrease the likelihood of a deadlock.

I know that sp_lock() can be used to show current locks but to use this I would have to open a transaction with a lockhold hint.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why don't you try activity monitor. It shows the running processes, and details about the locks. You can find which process is locked using session id

Comment: No, there's no such thing. You can execute the query and use profiler or trace flag 1200 to see the locks actually taken out though.

Comment: @MartinSmith. You are saying no activity monitor in sql server?

Comment: @bmsqldev activity monitor doesn't do what the OP asks for.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion to find the lock order; even via the contents of showplan_all?

Comment: Both of my suggestions show the lock order.

Comment: Extended events also work.